# download ios application on my iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I already created my privilege profile and run the application on my iphone and everything is going well. But when the device was disconnected from the mac after a while the application may not run especially if an exception is thrown it never run again until you reRun it by connecting the device to the mac and run the application from xcode itself.

I know that there is some way to archive the application and download it to the device as an .ipa file. But how can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you build your app in Xcode to your device, it will "crash" if you remove the connection from your device to your computer (if you haven't stopped the build). However, if you build your app to your device then press "Stop" you can later launch your app directly from your device.

If you would like to distribute your app for beta testing or later for app store you will have to Archive your app. You do that by going to "Product" -> "Archive".

Comment: After Creating the .ipa you can sync the app to your device using itunes.

Comment: archive is not clickable !!

Comment: @etab, what do you mean?

Comment: i can not click on it : its color is gray

Comment: i had my application of the kind : Application , is that correct ?

Comment: What do you want to do? Would you only like to test your app on your device even if it's not connected to your computer? Or do you want to send out your app to testers?

Comment: i want to add my application to my and my partner devices in order to test it we both

Comment: In that case: "Product" -> "Archive" -> "Distribute" -> "Save for enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment". Be sure that your partners device is added to the developer portal before doing that, so you'll need the UDID of that device. If your physically near your partners device just build it your app on that device as well instead of doing an archive.

Comment: More info can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Comment: select distribution method :save built products OR export as xcode archive ?